# whats the best method or testing website compatibility

Tags: html, css

ive been making a website for a charity i volenteer with and want to check it for browser compatibility so ive been using browser shots website to show me give me images of what the site looks like in diferent browser configurations

my question is how much backwards compatibility should i be looking for ive currently been aiming for the last 5 versions of the major browsers so ie chrome firefox opera and safari is it neesary to make sure the last 5 versions are suported or should i be aiming to make say the last 2 versions or even more compatible the code is most likeley compatible with most versions but some parts like rounded corners in css i know arnt suported so most people with older browsers may not see it corectly should i make it viewable for them or just have a pop up box lil youtube that says your using a older browser for best results use a newer browser and link them to it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We practice supporting IE 6, 7, 8, 9, Firefox 3.6+, Chrome 15+

And we test by using virtual machines with the actual browsers installed.

But its best to look at who is visiting you site, and cater to what they use. I.e. use Google Analytics to see which browsers are you most popular and focus on them first.

Comment: +1... abosultely **nothing** can accurately simulate all the quirks and bugs of the actual browser itself.

Comment: i believe that browsershots is basically a vm cluster of diferent os's and it just sends jobs so the servers because the screenshots show the browser itself rather than a render of the website also last time i checked they have a volenteer service where ou can setup your own vm to add to there cluster and actually while i think about it it seems kinda insecure if i was doing a confidential project to be sending it off to some unknown strangers vm server to get screen shotted will have to take that in mind in future

Answer (score 1):

It depends mostly on your target audience actually. Non-IE browsers aren't a big problem when going down the versions, so you might notice that even the last 5 versions of them are rendering the page completely, or almost-completely (no major flaws) the same. What you want to take care of is IE. With the current version 9, it's still unbeliveable that some people are still using IE6, but that's a sad truth. You just need to see if it's worth optimizing your website for oldies like that one. A link to a newer version seems like the best solution and there are even some plugins for this that immitate the native IE info toolbars.

Also, be careful with html5 and css3.

UPDATE

See some helpful info [here](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Rounded_Corners___Border_Radius__css3_and_IE_versi-18564.html).

Comment: Agree totally. But there are a lot of differences between Firefox 3.x and 11/12.

Comment: True, but I didn't think we should go that deep since he's making a charity website with probably only a basic functionality. Again, my assumption can be wrong, so your point is noted.

Comment: Non-IE browsers do have problems going down the versions, take those that there were at the time of IE 6 and you'll see. And sadly, some people are also still using these browsers. Luckily they are not as popular.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should use a tool like [Microsoft Expression Web SuperPreview](http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/dd565874). This provides you with a view of your site side by side in your locally installed browsers. There's also a premium service whereby it will compare your site in a complete range of browsers and versions for comparisson.

Comment: "Ideally" you should be testing within the actual browser itself.

Comment: +1 What @Sparky672 said. Never forget that!

Comment: SuperPreview uses the engine of each browser to generate the preview image and therefore accurately displays the output that a user will experience using the same browser / version combination.

Answer (score 0):

Try [browsershots.org](http://browsershots.org/).

It is a nice website that outputs images how your website looks in other browsers.

Comment: BTW. Before testing you'll need to create empty robots.txt file on your server.

Comment: btw. In the first paragraph it says he was using it.